# How to do common Exception handling

Tags: java, spring, exception

Lets say I have about a hundred classes with this method signature, which is the only entry exit method for that class :

```
public Map<String,Object> doSome(Map arg1, map arg2)
```

and within the method body there is a try/catch block. The catch block catches Exception and rethrows a custom exception. Earlier the program would just abandon in the catch block. Now I need to be able to return a Map which has a key value like ("Exception", "Some went bad in this class"). One way to do it is to make an additional method within this doSome  method (and push the current code into the new one) and surround this method call with a try/catch and in the catch block catch the custom exception and write a generic method to populate the returning map 
What would be the best way to achieve this for all of those 100+ classes ?
I am wondering if such a thing can be achieved using Spring AOP ? But most of the spring advices I come across dont allow returning of values (meaning the control never bubbles back to where the exception was thrown from).  
It would be great if someone can point me to specific examples.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like something that can be solved with some functionality provided by a parent class.

Have each of your 100 classes (*really, 100??!*) extend an abstract parent class. Have the parent class define the `doSomething` method:

```
public Map<String,Object> doSome(Map arg1, Map arg2) {

  try {
    doSomething(arg1, arg2);
  } catch (Exception e) {
    // clever handling here
  }
}
```

Make sure the `doSomething()` method is defined as an abstract method in `ExceptionHandler`. Of course, better method names would be welcome.

Each of the subclasses would implement their own variation of `doSomething()`.

Comment: A little over 100. *Really*. :) All these classes are part of a codebase which is used/called by an external framework. So these classes are already extending that framework's class. So this is not an option

Comment: @happybuddha Could the parent class not extend the framework class?

Comment: sadly no. This is an existing application (which surprisingly terminate everything in the catch block) and the flexibility of such changes is less.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try Spring AOP type "After throwing advice - runs after the method throws an exception" You can look at the simple example here :
    http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-aop-examples-advice/